# Get first date of previous month

Tags: postgresql, date

Is there any way to get the first day of previous month other than

```
date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1 month') ?
```

I'm trying to save a query in a Report Designer software (DBxtra) but the software freezes while using the "interval" feature of PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
make_interval(month := 1)
'1 month'::interval
cast('1 month' as interval)
```

instead of `interval '1 month'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to calculate the previous month manually.

One approach is extract the month and subtract 1 if it is not 12(in this case you return 1):

```
SELECT to_timestamp(concat(EXTRACT(YEAR from current_date), '-',CASE (EXTRACT(MONTH from current_date)) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE (EXTRACT(MONTH from current_date)-1) END,'-', 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

If you need it without timezone:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(concat(EXTRACT(YEAR from current_date), '-',CASE (EXTRACT(MONTH from current_date)) WHEN 12 THEN 1 ELSE (EXTRACT(MONTH from current_date)-1) END,'-', 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD')::timestamp without time zone;
```